# parse nest tag with smack in android

Tags: android, smack

```
<message xmlns="jabber:client" from="33@localhost/21303386561456721493183510" to="15@localhost" id="09547C30-1BE8-40EA-9937-2F168913DAB3" type="chat"><body><text>The</text><date>2016-02-29 04:51:59</date></body><delay xmlns="urn:xmpp:delay" from="localhost" stamp="2016-02-29T04:51:58Z">Offline Storage</delay><x xmlns="jabber:x:delay" stamp="20160229T04:51:58"/></message>
```

above is what i send to server, but while the message is parsed, it has a exception Non-empty element tag not followed by text, and i could see a unparsable packet with setting of ParsingExceptionCallback

```
<text xmlns='jabber:client'>Shushes</text><date xmlns='jabber:client'>2016-02-29 04:45:04</date></body><delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay' from='localhost' stamp='2016-02-29T04:45:04Z'>Offline Storage</delay><x xmlns='jabber:x:delay' stamp='20160229T04:45:04'/></message>
```

would that be possible to define own parser to parse this type of structure. i am using smack4.1.6